# activity tracing message not show in thread info

Tags: xcode, ios8.1, activity-tracing

I am trying to get message in thread info after crash. code is
 `- (IBAction)btn_crash:(id)sender {
    os_activity_initiate("activity", OS_ACTIVITY_FLAG_DEFAULT, ^{
        os_trace_debug("test tracing");
        [self testtracing]; 
    });
}`
but what i get is

```
**(lldb) thread info
```

thread #1: tid = 0x523d, 0x000000010b67a282 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT**

not the activity message please help.

Comment: I tired the same and it works with Xcode 7.3. If it crashes in [self testtracing], the message "test tracing" will appear in the crash report.